# Angular 4 - Can't open popup using multiple outlets

Tags: angular, typescript, routerlink, router-outlet

I'm developing an Angular 4 application with some chained outlet routes and I'm having some trouble to make a popup appear using route.
Basically the popup route's path is "pages/admin/user-management/new"
the routes are configured this way:

The first component defines this template and route:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
{
    path: 'pages',
    loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule',
    data: {
        authorities: ['ROLE_USER']
    },
    canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
}
```

The pages module defines this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
{
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#BaseAdminModule',
}
```

And finally the admin module defines this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
{
    path: 'user-management/new',
    component: UserDialogComponent,
    outlet: 'popup'
}
```

However I can't figure out how configure the routerLink in a way that the popup is exhibited, tryied this and a lot of variations:

```
[routerLink]="['/',{ outlets: { primary:'pages/admin',popup: ['user-management/new'] } }]"
```

but I always receive:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'user-management%2Fnew'